# Html Agility Pack: DescendantsOrSelf() not returning HTML element

Tags: parsing, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I have some HTML, eg:

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="ContentManagedTargetPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxx.ContentManagedTargetPage" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CxCMS" Namespace="xxx.ContentManagement.ASPNET.UI" Assembly="xxx.ContentManagement.ASPNET" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Content Managed
    </h2>
    <p>
        Put content here.
        [<CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder Key="keyThingy" runat="server" />]
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

And I want to find all the instances of the CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder element.

I'm using HTML Agility Pack, which seems the best fit.

However, despite looking at the [meagre] documentation, I can't get my code to work.

I would expect the following to work:

```
string searchForElement = "CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder";
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> contentPlaceHolderHtmlNodes = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants(searchForElement);
int count = contentPlaceHolderHtmlNodes.Count();
```

But I get nothing back.

If I change to DescendantsOrSelf, I get the document node back, "#document" - which is incorrect:

```
string searchForElement = "CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder";
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> contentPlaceHolderHtmlNodes = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantsOrSelf(searchForElement);
int count = contentPlaceHolderHtmlNodes.Count();
```

I also tried using LINQ:

```
string searchForElement = "CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder";
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> contentPlaceHolderHtmlNodes = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantsOrSelf().Where(q=>q.Name==searchForElement);
int count = contentPlaceHolderHtmlNodes.Count();
```

As neither of these methods work, I moved onto using SelectNodes, instead:

```
string searchForElement = "CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder";
string xPath="//"+searchForElement // "//CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder"
var nodes= HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath);
```

This just throws the exception: "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.". I can't find any way of adding namespace management to the HtmlDocument object.

What am I missing, here? The DescendantsOrSelf() method works if using a "standard" HTML tag, such as "p", but not the one I have. Surely it should work? (It needs to!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual I spend an hour or so playing, I ask the question, and I figure it out seconds after.

When searching using DescendantsOrSelf(), the node name must be in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is actually ASPX. If you're parsing the ouput of that page, it's doubtful that `<CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder Key="keyThingy" runat="server" />` actually renders as that on the client side. Look at the html source on the client, find the output tags that correspond to the `<CxCMS:ContentManagedPlaceHolder Key="keyThingy" runat="server" />`, and then use those in `HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants`.

On the other hand, if you're parsing the ASPX source, you may need to tweak your input to `HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants` so that the HtmlAgilityPack recognizes it, however keep in mind that ASPX != html and I don't think the HtmlAgilityPack is built to parse it.

Edit: Looking through HtmlNode.cs in the HtmlAgilityPack source code, it looks like you're right about it needing to be lowercase due to the following two sections:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets this node's name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            if (_name == null)
            {
                Name = _ownerdocument._text
                                     .Substring(_namestartindex, _namelength);
            }
            return _name != null ? _name.ToLower() : string.Empty;
        }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
```

and

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all descendant nodes with matching name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Descendants(string name)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode node in Descendants())
            if (node.Name == name)
                yield return node;
    }
```

Note the `_name.ToLower()` in the getter for `Name`, and the case-sensitive `if (node.Name == name)` in the `Decendants` method. This is the same check used the the `DescendantsAndSelf`, `Element` and `Elements` methods.

Comment: Yes, I am working with ASPX source. It seems to work in the tests I have done so far, after figuring the lower-case thing out! Thanks.